# Rescue u-boot boot-partition with encrypted root filesystem

Tags: u-boot, rescue

I've installed a Debian on my BananaPi according to [this section](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Allwinner#Installing_from_an_SD_card_image). After manually configuring the partitions (/boot on SD-card, / and swap are LVM volumes in a LUKS partition on a SSD), the debian-installer took care of setting up /boot properly.

After ugrading to stable from oldstable recently, I can't unlock the LUKS partition anymore: When entering the password during boot, the system seems to hang (no error message, but device is not unlocked).

The device is not broken though. I've temporarily installed an entire debian on the SD-card, which allows mount my root partition on the SSD. (I am also able to chroot into it.)

Now I know how to rescue a grub bootloader using a live image via grub-install/grub-update, but I don't know any of the u-boot magic. Do I need to reinstall u-boot? Do I need to create a new initrd? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you update the kernel when you update OS? If you remember which version of kernel you had, check if you have modules for him in /lib/modules/kernel_version

Comment: Yes there was a kernel update. I don't recall which kernel I had, but I certainly didn't delete one. /lib/modules/ contains the folders 3.16.0-4-armmp-lpae and 4.9.0-6-armmp-lpae; so I assume 3.16 was my old kernel. My old /boot also contains files for these two kernels.

Comment: So I think this is the reason why your system can't start as u-boot (uImage) try to load modules that not exists.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: The solution will be (re)compile the kernel you have installed (after chroot to BPI with all required built-in kernel options you use in boot process). You should look for uImage file for your old kernel version, but can be the other one reason - the old kernel version use old glibc and couldn't start up (load modules) with updated packages.